# Searching and sorting values

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I try to scan the input one-by-one using charAt and sorting the letters of alphabet. If there is 2 'a's in the input the list array should start with 2. If there is 1 'b' in the input list[1] = 1. If c is used 3 times list[2] = 3. I want to have this for all letters in English.
For example if the input is "I bought a car."
The output should be 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
Note : The method is not case sensitive.

error: method sortInput in class sorting cannot be applied to given types; in line 24
What should I do?

UPDATE : Now I get an output but I get an 26-length array which all has 0's for 26 times.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sorting 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input;
        int i;
        int[] list = new int[26];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an input");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        for(i = 0; i <= list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(sortInput(Integer.toString(list[i]))) + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] sortInput(String input)
    {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        char k,l;
        int i, j;
        String alphabet;
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] letter = new char[26];
        int[] list = new int[26];
        j = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= alphabet.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            k = alphabet.charAt(i);
            letter[i] = k;  
        }
        for(i = 0; i <= input.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            l = input.charAt(i);        
            if(letter[i] == l)
            {
                for(i = 0; i <= input.length() - 1; i++)
                {
                   if(letter[i] == l)
                   {
                       j = 0;
                       j++;
                   }
                }
            }
            list[i] = j;        
        }
        return list;    
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? What problems are you running into?

Comment: I edited the question. Now it has error message.

Comment: so what is line 24? what did you do to debug? what does the error message mean do you thing, what values do your variables have, etc etc.

Comment: List is int type but your parameter is String type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance method `sortInput(String)` doesn't apply to `sortInput(int)`.

This

```
sortInput(list[i])
```

could be something like

```
sortInput(Integer.toString(list[i]))
```

or change the method to take an `int`. Or maybe you wanted

```
sortInput(input)
```

but it will also need to be `static` (or you'll need an instance) as noted by [@MikeKobit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627727/mike-kobit) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584574/2970947).

**Edit**

Based on your comments. Pass in `input` and your method should look something like

```
public static int[] sortInput(String input) {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    int[] list = new int[26];
    for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            list[ch - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "I bought a car.";
    int[] out = sortInput(input);
    for (int i : out) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Edit 2**

Without `toCharArray()`,

```
public static int[] sortInput(String input) {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    int[] list = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0, len = input.length(); i < len; i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            list[ch - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I made the method static I also wrote sortInput(Integer.toString(list[i])). Now I get an output but instead of what I wanted I get a 26-length array which all has 0's for 26 times.

Comment: I want it to count the each letter and assign the array according to it. There's an example at the beginning of the code.

Comment: @harold_finch Edited. Your code wasn't doing that. And you needed to pass in input.

Comment: Exactly. This is the output I want.

Comment: Is there another way to do it? Without using toCharArray() method.

Comment: @harold_finch Edited again.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the method `sortInput`, which is an instance method, from a static context. You can either instantiate the class you are trying to call the method on or in this case it seems like you would want that method to be `static`.

```
public static int[] sortInput(String input)
```

You are also trying to call that method with the incorrect type parameter.

```
int[] list = new int[26];
...
sortInput(list[i])
```

You are currently trying to call your method with an `int`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your

```
System.out.print(sortInput(list[i]) + " ");
```

with

```
public int[] sortInput(String input)
```

You are trying to call it with something else than it expects.